# Showing attached images of certain size in Wordpress posts

Tags: image, wordpress, attachment

I am currently using WordPress to build my portfolio website. The site consists of:

- a homepage showing "project" posts (using post categories).
- an about us page
- a projects page (very similar to homepage) showing thumbnails and titles of recent projects.
- a project detail page (this is a click through from either the homepage or projects page and shows detail on a particular project.

On the project detail page I have an image slider which I want to show the work associated with that project. I have used the following function call to return all images associated with the post:
`<?php display_images_in_list('medium'); ?>`which calls the following function:

```
function display_images_in_list($size = thumbnail) {

if($images = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'numberposts'    => -1, // show all
    'post_status'    => null,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
            'order'           => 'ASC',
))) {
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $attimg   = wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID,'medium');
        echo "<div class='slide'>".$attimg."</div>";
    }
}
```

}

Even though I have specified I would like medium images returned my slider still features the thumbnail image which I uploaded to show on another page.

How can I show only medium images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you upload image as attachment to post wp creates thumbnails. You cannot upload a thumbnail. If you upload big image, and thumb image both will be shown. You need to upload only big images and than it will show medium size as you wish.